# Prevent Drupal text format from filtering special tags

Tags: html, drupal

I'm working on implementing a service from a vendor that requires me to add a 'custom' tag to my page.

For instance:

`<abc:app></abc:app>`

The text formats on my Drupal site are filtered and I can't figure out how to allow this specific tag. I can get `<abc></abc>` on the page but when I try to include the `:app` it filters it out.

I've tried adding the following to the text format's allowed HTML elements and attributes:

- abc:app
- abc:app
- abc[*] (this re-writes `:app` ad `app=""`)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is maybe editor related. You can create your custom text format and disable filter *Limit allowed HTML tags* or you can always use PHP code text format.